# Use pure Ant to implement if else condition (check command line input)

Tags: ant

I am a newbie in Ant. My ant script receives a user input variable named "**env**" from command line:

e.g. `ant doIt -Denv=test`

The user input value could be "*test*","*dev*" or "*prod*".

I also have the "`doIt`" target:

```
<target name="doIt">
  //What to do here?
</target>
```

In my target, I would like to create the following **if else** condition for my ant script:

```
if(env == "test")
  echo "test"
else if(env == "prod")
  echo "prod"
else if(env == "dev")
  echo "dev"
else
  echo "You have to input env"
```

That's to check which value user has inputted from command line, then, print a message accordingly.

I know with **ant-Contrib**, I can write ant script with `<if> <else>` . **But** for my project, I would like to use pure Ant to implement **if else** condition. Probably, I should use `<condition>` ?? But I am not sure how to use `<condition>` for my logic. Could some one help me please?

Comment: If you are a newbie to Ant, then consider using [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) instead. It's much easier.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can create few targets and use `if`/`unless` tags.

```
<project name="if.test" default="doIt">

    <target name="doIt" depends="-doIt.init, -test, -prod, -dev, -else"></target>

    <target name="-doIt.init">
        <condition property="do.test">
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="test" />
        </condition>
        <condition property="do.prod">
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="prod" />
        </condition>
        <condition property="do.dev">
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="dev" />
        </condition>
        <condition property="do.else">
            <not>
                <or>
                <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="test" />
                <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="prod" />
                <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="dev" />
                </or>
            </not>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="-test" if="do.test">
        <echo>this target will be called only when property $${do.test} is set</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="-prod" if="do.prod">
        <echo>this target will be called only when property $${do.prod} is set</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="-dev" if="do.dev">
        <echo>this target will be called only when property $${do.dev} is set</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="-else" if="do.else">
        <echo>this target will be called only when property $${env} does not equal test/prod/dev</echo>
    </target>

</project>
```

Targets with `-` prefix are private so user won't be able to run them from command line.

Comment: Thanks for this valuable information (Targets with - prefix are private so user won't be able to run them from command line.)

Comment: I understand that in 2013 ant 1.9 is not released. Ant 1.9 has native support for if and unless. https://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html. This will be useful for people who come here due to google ;)

Answer (score 1):

If any of you require a plain **if/else** condition (without elseif); then use the below:

Here I am dependent on a env variable DMAPM_BUILD_VER, but it may happen that this variable is not set in the env. So I need to have mechanism to default to a local value.

```
    <!-- Read build.version value from env variable DMAPM_BUILD_VER. If it is not set, take default.build.version. -->
    <property name="default.build.version" value="0.1.0.0" />
    <condition property="build.version" value="${env.DMAPM_BUILD_VER}" else="${default.build.version}">
        <isset property="env.DMAPM_BUILD_VER"/>
    </condition>
```