# prompt user for input in ant and take action based on input

Tags: ant

I would like to be able to prompt an user for input during the execution of ant.
Pseudo code for what I am trying to do is:

```
echo "Enter y or n:"
read yorn
if [ $yorn = 'y' ]
then
   echo "$yorn" > /tmp/junk
fi
```

Here is what I have and it does not work:

```
 41         <target name="-after-build">
 42                 <input message="What's your name?" addproperty="your-name" validargs="Bob,Fred" />
 43                 <echo>What's up, ${your-name}?</echo>
 44                 <exec executable="/bin/echo">
 45                         <arg value="${your-name}"/>
 46                         <redirector output="/tmp/junk" alwayslog="true"/>
 47                 </exec>
 48                 <target name="ask_if_install">
 49                         <input message="do you want to run rsync?" addproperty="install_it" validargs="y,n" />
 50                 </target>
 51                 <target name="install.it"
 52                         if="install_it"
 53                         depends="ask_if_install">
 54                         <exec executable="/bin/echo">
 55                                 <arg value="${install_it}"/>
 56                                 <redirector output="/tmp/junk2" alwayslog="true"/>
 57                         </exec>
 58                 </target>
 59         </target>
```

Here is the output that I am getting:

```
build.xml:48: Problem: failed to create task or type target
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389544/use-pure-ant-to-implement-if-else-condition-check-command-line-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [input task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html)

```
<project  xmlns:if="ant:if"  xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

    <input  message="Enter y or n:" validargs="y,n" addproperty="yes.or.no" />

    <condition property="yes.is.true">
      <equals arg1="${yes.or.no}" arg2="y" />
    </condition>


    <concat destfile="junk" if:true="${yes.is.true}">${yes.or.no}</concat>

</project>
```

EDIT: you can use `if:true, if:set, unless:true,...` in almost all ant tasks

```
<exec executable="echo" if:true="${yes.is.true}">
    <arg value="${yes.or.no}" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question is a little misleading.  I planned to replace the `/bin/echo` with a more complex command, like `rsync --bunch of args`. Does `<exec ...` have an `if` option?

Comment: @Red Cricket See ma EDIT

Comment: dang. I am getting `The prefix "if" for attribute "if:true" associated with an element type "exec" is not bound.` when I try to do `<exec executable="/usr/local/bin/rsync" if:true="${do.install}"> ...`

Comment: @Red Cricket  do you have <project  xmlns:if="ant:if"  xmlns:unless="ant:unless">

Comment: Oops! I forgot that bit.  Can I do this? `<target name="-after-build" xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">` or is better to put the xmlns options in the project tag?

Comment: you should add it to the project tag

Comment: Thanks for all your help Oleg.  I am still having problems though. Could you please look at me new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538385/build-xml-ignoring-echo-tags-and-if-options  Thanks!